# Is there a good source for Lambda brain teasers

Tags: c#, resources, lambda

I'm looking for something similar to [SQL for Smarties by Joe Celko](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1558605762).  More specifically I'm interested in .Net 3.5 or 4.0.

Comment: First time I've heard of that book, thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 2):

The seasoned schemer

http://books.google.com/books?id=vKIvIXSxcCgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=the+little+schemer&source=gbs_similarbooks_s&cad=1#v=onepage&q=the%20little%20schemer&f=false